# Drag after long press

Tags: qt, qml, drag, qtquick2

I want to drag my custom buttons QML after a long press over them. I've implemented that behaviour, however the problem is that after enabling `drag`, I need to press button once again to actually start dragging. How should I implement this mechanism if I want to move buttons without releasing after long press?

Here is my button code (`onReleased` and `onLongPressed` are my own signals):

```
ButtonWidget.SoftButtonUI
{
    id:softButtonDelegate2
    x:500
    y:300
    labelText: "button"
    iconImageSource: path
    isGrayedOut: false

    Drag.active: dragArea2.drag.active
    Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
    Drag.hotSpot.y: 10
    onReleased:
    {
        console.log("onClicked")
    }

    onLongPressed:
    {
        console.log("onLongPressed")
        dragArea2.enabled = true
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: dragArea2
        enabled: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: parent
        onReleased: parent.Drag.drop()
        onClicked: {
            console.log("MouseArea onClicked")
        }
        onPressAndHold: {
            console.log("MouseArea  onPressAndHold")
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking you can connect different signals and concatenate operations as discussed in this [page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals). You should have a look at it since it is full of nice and useful information.

However, when it comes to mouse events, an interesting approach to events concatenation is given by `MouseEvent`s acceptation. [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html#accepted-prop) says about `MouseEvent::accepted`:

> Setting accepted to true prevents the mouse event from being
>   propagated to items below this item. Generally, if the item acts on
>   the mouse event then it should be accepted so that items lower in the
>   stacking order do not also respond to the same event.

In this case we can take the opposite approach by *not* accepting the event. This way the `pressed` event can be used to *both* activate the drag and actually perform it. Then the `MouseEvent` can be accepted (implicitly) in the `release` event, occurring at the end of the drag.

Here is a simple example following this approach. As the mouse is pressed and hold the `drag.target` is set and drag can start, whereas when the mouse is released the `drag.target` is removed, removing the dragging behaviour. To test it, just press and hold the mouse over the rectangle and when it changes color just drag it.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: item
        border.width: 2
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 100
        state: "BASE"

        states: [
            State {
            name: "BASE"
            PropertyChanges { target: mouseArea; drag.target: undefined}
            PropertyChanges { target: item; color: "steelblue"}
        },
            State {
            name: "DRAGGABLE"
            PropertyChanges { target: mouseArea; drag.target: item}
            PropertyChanges { target: item; color: "darkblue"}
        }
        ]


        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag{
                // target:  NOT SET HERE
                minimumX: 0
                minimumY: 0
                maximumX: parent.parent.width - parent.width
                maximumY: parent.parent.height - parent.height
                smoothed: true
            }

            onPressAndHold: {
                item.state = "DRAGGABLE"
                mouse.accepted = false      // mouse event is USED but NOT CONSUMED...
            }

            onReleased: {
                item.state = "BASE"         // mouse event acceptation occurs here!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This simple approach should work perfectly also with your custom signals.

Comment: Note that properties are automatically unset if we leave the DRAGGABLE state. There is no need to set everything back in the base state.

Comment: Yep, yep. Useless state, indeed. Not sure why I've added it.